# Using of dvips color on text

Tags: color

I am trying to use the different colors apart from the standard color(red,green,blue etc.) by xcolor package for a pdflatex. But it shows error on the line where I declared the color name showing xcolor does not include the color. It will be of help if someone provides me the actual code. My code are as following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{graphics}
%\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colordvi}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\input{epsf}
\begin{center}
{\RawSienna{\Large \bf  
Tiltle}
}
\end{center}

\vspace{.5in}
\begin{center}
{\em text}

\vspace{.2in}

{\Orchid{{\large \bf name}}}

\vspace{.2in}

{\DarkOrchid{\sf Supervisor : name}}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.4in}

\begin{center}
{\sf text }

\vspace{.2in}

{\bf text}
\end{center}

\vspace{1.4in}

\begin{center}
{\sf text

\vspace{.2in}

text}
\end{center}

\vspace{.45in}

\centerline{date}
%\begin{center}
%\vfill
%\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: check xcolor manual. there you will find that `DarkOrchid` is defined via `x11names`. However, your use of colors is wrong. color names aren't commands ...

Comment: `epsf` and `epsfig` are  obsolete, and should be replaced by `graphicx` (with an `x` – needless to load `graphics`. Needless to load `color` when you load `xcolor` too, and finally `colordvi` is for `plainTeX`, not LaTeX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me elaborate my comment above. your use of color names as commands are wrong. also you use obsolete commands `\bf`, `\sf` etc. trry the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,  x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
%\input{epsf}
\begin{center}
\textcolor{RawSienna}{\Large\textbf{Tiltle}}

\vspace{.5in}

\emph{text}

\vspace{.2in}

\textcolor{Orchid}{\large\textbf{name}}

\vspace{.2in}

\textcolor{DarkOrchid}{\textsf{Supervisor: name}}
\end{center}

etc \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Clean up your package list:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\color{DarkOrchid}Tiltle

\end{document}
```